# Behaviour of SIOCGARP IOCTL when entry not cached

Tags: c, linux, networking, ioctl, arp

**Objective**

To get the MAC address of the iOS devices connected to my embedded device (arm-linux) which acts as an access point. There are no iOS API's to get the MAC address of the iOS device, so I can't have an 'Application layer' scheme to do this

**Proposed alternative**

I am planning to use 'SIOCGARP' to get the MAC address of the connected device.

**Clarifications**

As I understand, `SIOCGARP` reads the IP-MAC address mapping from the local cache. So, I have few questions here

1. What will happen if the requested entry is not there will an explicit ARP request be sent to find the mapping of MAC address for the given IP address.
2. If -#1 is not done, then will doing a 'ping' before invoking `SIOCGARP` decrease the likely hood of entries being unavailable

**Additional notes**

I referred few other stack overflow questions, which mainly discussed on how to send a ARP request. But am looking for a short cut by which I can avoid sending ARP requests and receiving ARP response.

Comment: Short answer: 1. No, 2. Yes. Depending on the method you use you might have to wait a few ms after triggering an echo request (ping) to the target, since the arp cache gets filled asynchronously.